# How can I use token to call authorized API method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

I have already created a login component from a client and I just want to extract or use the response token  from the server to view data from authorized controller. Here's my login procedure.

```
private async Task LoginUser()
    { 
            var xx = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/login/loginuser", loginmodel);
    }
```

Comment: Pls give us more information. I you are posting  Login and Password you usually don't need token. You should get it back after successfull checking login and password.

Comment: Yes, I have successfully implemented the login page, what I want to do is to extract the token and use to  access the authorized controller. Like in Postman the response token will be just be copied and paste in the box. But I don't how to do this in blazor.

Comment: Is var xx your token? How do you get  a token from API?

Comment: the var xx will hold the response of my login API.

Comment: I understand it. What value var xx will hold?

Comment: I believe the token. Let me show the last part of my login API  

                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                        expiration = token.ValidTo
                    });

Comment: I don't see xx in your last code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to change your code to this

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, loginModel);
string token= await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
```

To accees Api service that needs token authorizatin use this code (also you can check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
         var httpClient =new HttpClient(); //or you can use your http client 
                                   //if you use HttpClient Factory.
         var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.... , 
            ...YourApiUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        .......
         .....
```

Comment: I guess there's an error on getting my token. Do you have any idea how  to really get the token? I tried my login API in Postman it perfectly response the token but in blazor I can't see it.

Comment: Could you please include in your question the full Task LoginUser() code?